# How to Bind custom filter value in Smart table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

AS per a requirement I need to bind a custom filter bar value with the smart table. They don't want a smart filter. So I implemented the filter bar with a go button. With on click go button, I need to bind the filter value with the smart table.

My Xml Code :

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable_ResponsiveTable" demandPopin="false" tableType="Table" editable="false"
    entitySet="EntitySet" showVariantManagement="true" useVariantManagement="true" useTablePersonalisation="true"
    header="Request Pending My Action" showRowCount="true" useExportToExcel="true" enableAutoBinding="true" initialise="onInitialise"
    persistencyKey="SmartTablePKey" smartVariant="pageVariantId" showFullScreenButton="true"
    initiallyVisibleFields="Vin,Acind,Bukrs,Ekorg,Zzprimary,Zzscom1,Bunit,Lifnr,Name1,Status,Uname,Credat,Cretim"></smartTable:SmartTable>
```

controller :

```
onSearch: function() {
        var Vin = new Filter("Vin", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Vin").getValue());
        var Acind = new Filter("Acind", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Acind").getValue());
        var Bukrs = new Filter("Bukrs", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Bukrs").getValue());
        var Ekorg = new Filter("Ekorg", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Ekorg").getValue());
        var Zzprimary = new Filter("Zzprimary", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Zzprimary").getValue());
        var Zzscom1 = new Filter("Zzscom1", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Zzscom1").getValue());
        var Bunit = new Filter("Bunit", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Bunit").getValue());
        var Lifnr = new Filter("Lifnr", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Lifnr").getValue());
        var Name1 = new Filter("Name1", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Name1").getValue());
        var Status = new Filter("Status", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Status").getValue());
        var Uname = new Filter("Uname", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Uname").getValue());
        var Credat = new Filter("Credat", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Credat").getValue());
        var Cretim = new Filter("Cretim", "EQ", this.getView().byId("Cretim").getValue());
        var aFilters = [];
        aFilters.push(new Filter([Vin, Acind, Bukrs, Ekorg, Zzprimary, Zzscom1, Bunit, Lifnr, Name1, Status, Uname, Credat, Cretim], true));
        var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("smartTable_ResponsiveTable");
        oSmartTable.getTable().bindRows("/EntitySet", null, null, aFilters);

    },
```

Kindly provide a code to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

SmartTable works differently. 
Here is the Pseudocode.

```
onSearch: function(){
 <Get reference to SmartTable>
 <call rebindTable() API on SmartTable>
}
```

While defining SmartTable, attach `onBeforeRebindTable` to event `beforeRebindTable`.

```
onBeforeRebindTable : function(){
 <get all filters from your custom filterbar into aFilters as you did in your current code.>
 <oBindingParams.filters = aFilters>
}
```

Comment: Hi Krisho..  i tried the below and its not working . Guide me .

Comment: onSearch: function(oEvent) {
   var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("smartTable_ResponsiveTable");
   // oSmartTable.getTable().bindRows("/TInboxOpenReqSet", null, null, aFilters);
   oSmartTable.rebindTable();
  },

Comment: AM getting the below error in console. ODataMetadata-dbg.js:849 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Ignore the above :   the below one i tried    onBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {  var aFilters = [];
   var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");   aFilters.push(new Filter([Vin, Acind, Bukrs, Ekorg, Zzprimary, Zzscom1, Bunit, Lifnr, Name1, Status, Uname, Credat, Cretim], true));
   oBindingParams.filters = aFilters; },

Comment: Also getting the below in console.

Comment: 2019-04-10 19:21:58.580929 The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed400,Bad Request,{"error":{"code":"005056A509B11EE1B9A8FEC11C21178E","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Invalid token detected at position 209"},"innererror":{"transactionid":"855B0C670F3700A0E005C877B9DD7F35","timestamp":"20190410135158.4473340","Error_Resolution":{"SAP_Transaction":"Run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system (System Alias ) and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details","SAP_Note":"See SAP

Comment: Thanks ! This helped me !